task (lowercased) vs. Task (capitalized)
What's the difference?
task {
    // ... //
}
                
Task {
    // ... //
}

I discovered it by accident.
Task is the right struct, when you want to create an asynchronous task. But writing task doesn't cause a syntax error. I know the SwiftUI task-modifier. But what is the purpose written within general code?

You can write a modifier without the dot as part of other code but I am not sure it will work very well.
So the task you have is the same as the modifier version and is required to return a View meaning you should really be using Task if you are inside a function. Note that
Here is a silly example with a function that is declared inside a view that we can learn two things from, 1) the task closure is never executed, only "Hello" is printed 2) We can  add other modifiers here and they won't be useful either.
func silly() {
    Task {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        print("Hello")
    }


    task {
        try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))

        print("Hello 2")
    }

    font(.largeTitle)

}



But writing 'task' doesn't cause a syntax-error.

It does cause a compiler error. Try writing it in a global function.
func f() {
    task { } // cannot find symbol 'task'
}

So no, task { } cannot be used in "general code".

It doesn't cause a compiler error if you use it in the declaration of a View struct, e.g.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {}.onAppear {
            task {  } // this compiles
        }
    }
}

In this case task is referring to the task modifier. It is the same as self.task { }. This creates a View that is same as self, but with that task added, but since this is in onAppear, that view is discarded immediately and the task is not executed.
If you put it in the body however,
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        task {  }
    }
}

then this causes infinite recursion. To compute the body of ContentView, we need to find the body of self.task {  }. To do that we need to find the body of the task modifier. This involves finding the body of the view that it is modifying, so we need to find the body of self (ContentView), and this continues infinitely until stack overflow.
